# Detecting errors with auto.arima beforehand (xreg is rank deficient / system is exactly singular)

Tags: r

I'm running auto.arima with external regressors over K=3000 different time series. For some time series, I either get the error "Error in auto.arima(Train[, K], xreg = newxreg) : xreg is rank deficient" or "Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[1,1] = 0". As I can't investigate all those time series manually, I'd like to add a check to my code so that auto.arima is run without external regressors if one of those two issues occurs, instead of my for-loop stopping each time.

This is my simplified code:

```
for(K in seq(1,3000)) {
Model <- auto.arima(Train[,K],xreg=newxreg)
}
```

Below is one example where I get the error "Lapack routine...". In the first column, you see the values of Train[,K] and in columns 2-6 the values of the regressors, which are stored in newxreg. So what kind of 'if' check can I add here so that i don't use auto.arima with xreg for this particular example?

[image]